# Why does undivided switch case conditon not works

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
$xyz  = 14;
switch($xyz){
    case $xyz == 14:
        echo 'first';
    case ($xyz == 15 || $xyz == 16):
        echo 'second';
    break;
}
```

This echoes "firstsecond" though i expect it to see if the second case condition matches and NOT echo 'second'. How does that work exactly?

Comment: break after each case.

Comment: You are missing break statement after first case.